Fastest method for simultaneously removing a row and column from a pytorch tensor
I'm looking for a fast method for deletion of a row and column from a pytorch tensor simultaneously. Let t be a square 2D tensor of shape [l,l]. This question is similar to this question but this question deals with deletion along a single dimension. The operation I want can be achieved via:
 # index to delete
 idx = 499

 keep = [_ for _ in range(l)]
 keep.remove(idx)
 t = t[keep,:][:,keep]

 # t now has dimension [l-1,l-1]

but this is quite slow (list-indexing is not a tensor view op and the index is done in two parts). Can anyone recommend a faster way?
Here are a few of the other approaches I've tried.
# Double index with a list
    import torch
    import time

    l = 8000
    iterations = 500
    idx = 599

    t = torch.rand([l,l])

    # test 1 - double list index
    keep = [_ for _ in range(l)]
    keep.remove(idx)

    total = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
    
        start = time.time()
        t2 = t[keep,:][:,keep]
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        total += elapsed
    print("Took {:.1f}s for {} iterations, {}s/it".format(total,iterations,total/iterations))

Took 35.0s for 500 iterations, 0.07009070539474488s/it
# Double index with a tensor
(marginally faster in some cases than the above but both are non-contiguous memory operations)

    # test 2 - double tensor index
    keep = torch.tensor(keep)

    total = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
    
        start = time.time()
        t2 = t[keep,:][:,keep]
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        total += elapsed
    
    print("Took {:.1f}s for {} iterations, {}s/it".format(total,iterations,total/iterations))

Took 34.6s for 500 iterations, 0.06911029624938965s/it
# Concatenation
    # test 3 - concat_based approach

    total = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        start = time.time()
    
        t2 = torch.cat([torch.cat([t[:idx,:idx],t[idx+1:,:idx]],dim = 0),torch.cat([t[:idx,idx+1:],t[idx+1:,idx+1:]],dim = 0)],dim = 1)
    
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        total += elapsed
    
    print("Took {:.1f}s for {} iterations, {}s/it".format(total,iterations,total/iterations))

Took 31.1s for 500 iterations, 0.06218040370941162s/it
# Shift and delete the last row/column 
(which is a traditional indexing op that's fast but requires cloning `t`). This and the above approach are the fastest but don't scale nicely with having more than one row/column to delete (requiring either to do the deletions one at a time or else nest a conditional block for each possible variable number of deletions).

    # test 4 - shift and remove end approach
    total = 0

    for i in range(iterations):
        t2 = torch.clone(t)

        start = time.time()    
        t2[idx:-1,:] = t[idx+1:,:]
        t2[:,idx:-1] = t[:,idx+1:]
        t2 = t2[:-1,:-1]
    
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        total += elapsed
    
    print("Took {:.1f}s for {} iterations, {}s/it".format(total,iterations,total/iterations))

Took 26.5s for 500 iterations, 0.052913659572601315s/it
or, if I exclude the time to clone the tensor from the total time:
Took 11.7s for 500 iterations, 0.023439947128295897s/it
# Flatten into a 1D array for single indexing
    total = 0 
    for i in range(iterations):
    
        
        start = time.time()
        o = torch.ones(t.shape,dtype = int)
        o[:,idx] = 0
        o[idx,:] = 0
        o = o.view(-1).nonzero().squeeze(1)
        t2 = t.view(-1)[o].view(l-1,l-1)
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        total += elapsed

    print("Took {:.1f}s for {} iterations, {}s/it".format(total,iterations,total/iterations))

Took 87.1s for 500 iterations, 0.11186568689346313s/it
# 2D boolean mask indexing
(under the hood this seems to be roughly the same as the above and requires a reshaping `view` operation at the end as well (and the time taken is about the same)

    total = 0 
    for i in range(iterations):
        o = torch.ones(t.shape,dtype = bool)

        start = time.time()
        o[:,idx] = 0
        o[idx,:] = 0
        t2 = t[o].view(l-1,l-1)
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        total += elapsed

    print("Took {:.1f}s for {} iterations, {}s/it".format(total,iterations,total/iterations))

Took 86.1s for 500 iterations, 0.17228954696655274s/it
# Copy to empty tensor, per @trialNerror's answer:
total = 0 
for i in range(iterations):
   
    start = time.time()

    H,W = t.shape
    # Empty initialization, just a memory alloc
    t2 = torch.empty(H-1, W-1)
    # top-left block
    t2[:idx, :idx] = t[:idx, :idx]
    # top-right block
    t2[:idx, idx:] = t[:idx, idx+1:]
    # bottom-left block
    t2[idx:, :idx] = t[idx+1:, :idx]
    # bottom-right block
    t2[idx:, idx:] = t[idx+1:, idx+1:]

elapsed = time.time() - start
total += elapsed

Took 16.0s for 500 iterations, 0.031956102848052975s/it

Can you try the following ? It's similar to your option 4 but should be slighly faster because less copying happen and the exact amount of memory is allocated at the beginning.
The order (left->right top->bottom) should also the most cache-friendly you can get.
I don't think you can get much faster than what you have already with Pytorch's high level API. Further optimization would probably require tinkering with the copying kernel itself to improve the order of read/write operations
H,W = t.shape
# Empty initialization, just a memory alloc
t2 = torch.empty(H-1, W-1)
# top-left block
t2[:idx, :idx] = t[:idx; :idx]
# top-right block
t2[:idx, idx:] = t[:idx, idx+1:]
# bottom-left block
t2[idx:, :idx] = t[idx+1:, :idx]
# bottom-right block
t2[idx:, idx:] = t[idx+1:, idx+1:]

I agree that it does not scale well if you have many indices to remove. However in such case, I think you could keep this block decomposition structure and have two simple for-loops around this code to loop over your indices and copy the blocks in the right order

Added, thanks for the idea. I may need to modify the test script to include a variable number of deletions as some of these approaches will necessarily scale better than others
